# vhdl code for RAM memory

Tags: vhdl, ram

I have a question...what is the meaning of the two ****** in the following piece of code:
TYPE RAM IS ARRAY(0 TO 2 ****** ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1) OF std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);

Comment: The *exponentiating operator* `**` is predefined for each integer type and for each floating point type. Exponentiation with an integer exponent is equivalent to repeated multiplication of the left operand by itself for a number of times indicated by the absolute value of the exponent and from left to right; if the exponent is negative, then the result is the reciprocal of that obtained with the absolute value of the exponent. Exponentiation with a negative exponent is only allowed for a left operand of a floating point type. Exponentiation by a zero exponent results in the value one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being used to indicate exponentiation / raising *x* to the power of *y*. The `^` symbol commonly used for exponentiation in written math is used for the exclusive-or (XOR) operation in many languages, so the ones that also support exponentiation use a different symbol.

Comment: The circumflex accent character `^` is an 'other special character' in VHDL, a graphic character that has no special meaning in VHDL and is found only in extended identifiers or comments.